# Finding top 3 IDs with the largest count, by group - is it possible to avoid a triple nested query?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to find the top 3 'UserIDs' by 'Time' in terms of count in the 'Table'. An example of the input and output:

Table

```
ID    UserID    Time
1       A        '1'
2       A        '1'
3       B        '2'
4       B        '4'
5       B        '4'
etc
```

Desired result:

```
Time    UserID    Number    Rank
 '1'      A         17       1
 '1'      C         11       2
 '1'      Q         9        3
 '2'      B         13       1
 '2'      C         9        2
 '2'      M         7        3
etc
```

I've been able to accomplish this using a triple query but is there any way to simplify?

```
select userID, Number, time, Rank from (

select userID, Number, time,
Rank() over (partition by time order by Number DESC) as Rank

from

(select count(distinct(ID)) as Number, 
userID, 
time from table
group by 2, 3)

)

where Rank <= 3
```

I'm wondering if something like a 'HAVING' clause would be applicable here, since it seems like this would be very slow otherwise.

Comment: It usually helps to understand what you need if the sample data that you provide and desired result match each other. Besides, if your query produces correct results, then what's wrong with it? Is it too slow? Then provide detailed info about the table structure, indexes, data cardinality and the generated execution plan for your existing query.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I'm hoping to make the query itself more elegant, if there is a more direct approach available.

Comment: Unrelated but: `distinct` is ***not*** a function. And please post the real query, the query in your question is invalid syntax - the `rank ( .... )` part in the select list is incorrect and the main query is missing a `from` as far as I can tell (it would help if you formatted the query better)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I fixed the missing 'from' statements. I know distinct isn't a function but this is the syntax I'm used to and it works fine with postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Are you happy with this?

```
;with cte_ranking
as
(
select time, userid, count(time) as Number, rank() over (partition by time order by count(time) desc) as Rank
from
table
group by time,userid
) 
select * from cte_ranking
where Rank < 3
order by time
```

Comment: Postgres (and SQL in general) requires the statement termination character (the `;`) at the _end_ of the statement, not at the beginning

Comment: But CTEs specifically require terminator at the very beginning so as to make sure, if there is any statement before this, it should be terminated. It is MANDATORY. Not required if this itself is the first statement.

Comment: No CTEs do ***not*** *require* this. It might be mandatory for some Microsoft tools because Microsoft traditionally did not require to properly terminate statements. But it is most definitely not mandatory for Postgres.  And even Microsoft it will be required to **end** statements with a semicolon, not _start_ them. But this is a totally off-topic especially because this question is about Postgres and not SQL Server

Comment: Yes, I was talking in terms of MS-SQL where it is not required to terminate every statement. And if you run a CTE without semi-colon before it, say, in a Stored Procedure with other statements running before this. You will get an error saying -  "If this is intended to be a common table expression, you need to explicitly terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon."

Comment: But that's because you didn't properly **end** the previous statement, not because it is "mandatory" to _start_ a statement with a semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this query but its missing the rank columns because i didn't get the point of using it .. you can add later if its required :

```
select Time,UserID,count(1) as Number from table group by UserID,Time order by 1,3 desc
```

PS : if you would like to add the rank column, just try to add it in the select and group by.